# ideal gas adiabatic process

Tags: ideal-gas, adiabatic

I know how it is derived and here is my concern:

$dU=-dA=-d(pV)$

`p` is not a constant here, it depends on `V`. So my logic says, that

$d(p(V)*V) = p(V)dV$

is incorrect! It should be

$d(pV)=p(V)dV+Vdp$

What's wrong with my logic, thanks

Answer (score 0):

let's say P is a function of the form $P(V) =V^2 $.
You'll have to use the chain rule whenever you are differentiating a product of two functions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what *A* in *dA* stands for. But I'm assuming that it stands for work done.

If that is the case, then using **First Law of Thermodynamics**

$$dQ = \ dU \ + \ dW$$

which in an Adiabatic process would transform to

$$dU = -dW$$

But in the case of an ideal gas, the work done in expansion and compression is given by

$$dW = \  P(V) . \ dV$$ and not
$$dW = \ d(PV)$$